# Pi Zero W USB port dead or not dead?

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, troubleshooting

That is the question! This is my first Pi -> Zero W 2016 v1.1. USB problem happened after another very strange incident. After few days of normal operation, at boot logo screen my Pi suddenly turned off. I cut power and tried to switch it on again, but green LED didn't even light up, while SOC was heating immensely, so I quickly cut power again. This repeated few times and I already started to think that Pi is dead... Then I tried to connect it to PC USB for power and, suddenly it started working as normal. I figured out problem was in my DIY micro-USB power connector (I modified type-C into micro by soldering wires, I guess that was not very good quality work). I then remade my power micro-USB much more decently and now it works fine, no more problems. But...

After this incident, right after it, I tried to connect keyboard... And it stopped working, I checked keyboard - its fine, I also checked numerous other devices. Nothing works on Pi. I was using DIY keyboard micro-USB male too (not OTG, just data). Somehow it was working fine all days before incident. Maybe it's because it was not OTG that USB failed? Strangely though, it seems that USB still provides power, because when I connect mouse to it, mouse's LED is on, but no input from it OFC... Also while connecting to PC with nothing else connected through data USB cable, Pi starting up normally, but PC does not detect it as device. Since then I made DIY OTG cable and tested it with phone, it works perfectly. I again tested all the devices with Pi and USB still not responding.

At least I was able to set-up SSH from main PC before "The Great Incident", so I was able to collect some USB data:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lsusb -v
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.04
  iManufacturer           3
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 1
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12

dmesg
 Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.83+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 8.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1)) #1379 Mon Dec 14 13:06:05 GMT 2020
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x17c00000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 114688
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1008 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 114688 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 113680
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:65:56:91 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=058b43ad-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 376180K/458752K available (7816K kernel code, 712K rwdata, 2468K rodata, 508K init, 804K bss, 17036K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 27743 entries in 55 pages
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x2a8/0x4d8 with crng_init=0
[    0.000023] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
[    0.000073] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
[    0.000184] bcm2835: system timer (irq = 27)
[    0.000791] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000830] printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000910] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
[    0.050342] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.050654] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.050981] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.051009] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.053172] Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.053437] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.055162] Setting up static identity map for 0x8200 - 0x8238
[    0.056351] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.069094] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
[    0.069562] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.069602] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes, linear)
[    0.078661] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.080709] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.085400] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.091890] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.094137] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.094156] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.094321] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.098058] bcm2835-mbox 2000b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.100764] audit: type=2000 audit(0.090:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.120812] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2021-01-08 14:33, variant start
[    0.130830] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 194a85abd768c7334bbadc3f1911c10a7d18ed14
[    0.195302] bcm2835-dma 20007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.198498] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.198765] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.198905] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.199182] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.202108] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer
[    1.676355] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    1.676519] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.676904] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    1.677342] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    1.698628] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    1.699370] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.700797] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.700864] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.700947] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.701046] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    1.701234] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.701274] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.701787] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.703278] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.703296] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.703307] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.703317] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.705004] hw perfevents: no irqs for PMU, sampling events not supported
[    1.705080] hw perfevents: enabled with armv6_1176 PMU driver, 3 counters available
[    1.709980] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.710680] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    1.728582] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.730319] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.730384] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.730397] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.730431] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.733006] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.733030] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.733124] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    1.733141] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.733154] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.736833] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: FB found 1 display(s)
[    1.767895] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    1.810232] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Registered framebuffer for display 0, size 1920x1080
[    1.816669] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.821017] bcm2835-rng 20104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.821747] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1ec00000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
[    1.823577] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.824564] gpiomem-bcm2835 20200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x20200000
[    1.851133] brd: module loaded
[    1.869691] loop: module loaded
[    1.872415] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.873787] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.873833] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    2.532120] random: fast init done
[    2.602929] Core Release: 2.80a
[    2.602954] Setting default values for core params
[    2.603001] Finished setting default values for core params
[    2.803789] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    2.803811] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.803824] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.803840] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    2.803935] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    2.805035] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1074: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = d7d14000 dma = 0x97d14000 len=9024
[    2.805078] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    2.805098] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    2.805299] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:457: FIQ on core 0
[    2.805317] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:458: FIQ ASM at c05a0374 length 36
[    2.805347] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:497: MPHI regs_base at dc810000
[    2.805390] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.805471] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.805573] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
[    2.805640] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    2.805653] Init: Power Port (0)
[    2.806286] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    2.806314] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.806335] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.806352] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.83+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    2.806368] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
[    2.807877] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.808025] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.809436] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    2.809453] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    2.809464] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    2.809487] Module dwc_common_port init
[    2.810166] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.810753] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.813135] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    2.817346] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.817367] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.818368] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    2.819507] sdhost-bcm2835 20202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    2.819909] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.820848] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.821452] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.821827] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.821846] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.823760] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (ptrval)
[    2.826301] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    2.837463] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    2.840814] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.840888] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.841111] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.842721] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.842758] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.860325] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    2.860514] 20201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    2.864065] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    2.866657] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    2.866687] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    2.895807] sdhost: log_buf @ (ptrval) (97d13000)
[    2.932974] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    2.934839] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.936701] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.940017] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    2.944870] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.948901] of_cfs_init
[    2.949185] of_cfs_init: OK
[    2.971942] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=058b43ad-02...
[    3.011639] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    3.014840] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
[    3.017094] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 USD   7.48 GiB
[    3.021699]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    3.082277] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    3.102576] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.102743] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    3.104543] devtmpfs: mounted
[    3.110861] Freeing unused kernel memory: 508K
[    3.110880] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
[    3.110893] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    3.984556] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    4.225335] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    4.227866] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    4.278635] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    4.281178] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    4.295832] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    7.489482] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.532710] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.542018] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    7.543060] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.545163] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    7.548350] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    7.548960] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    7.551902] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    7.554549] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    7.558295] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    8.587624] i2c /dev entries driver
[    9.404426] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    9.598295] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[   10.002535] systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[   10.196673] systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
[   10.466088] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   11.962524] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   12.690689] systemd-journald[87]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   15.646347] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   15.795739] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   15.834907] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[   15.834941] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[   15.892971] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[   16.013326] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   16.105442] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.108687] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.115551] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.136244] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.148527] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.185974] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.225614] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   16.231910] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 8 channels
[   16.241055] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[   16.252460] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[   16.264386] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[   16.265719] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[   16.265780] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[   16.265818] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[   16.265851] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[   16.265880] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[   16.266494] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[   16.295431] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[   16.295561] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[   16.352572] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[   16.352661] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[   16.407860] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[   16.407958] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[   19.784009] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   20.446924] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   21.392601] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
[   21.423631] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   21.424210] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   21.456790] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-w.txt failed with error -2
[   21.748438] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   21.748698] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[   21.750275] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Oct 22 2019 01:59:28 version 7.45.98.94 (r723000 CY) FWID 01-3b33decd
[   35.190953] random: crng init done
[   35.190987] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   36.336836] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   37.257071] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   38.493248] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[   41.789733] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   43.233835] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms instead
```

I noticed some USB related messages in boot log:

```
[    0.198765] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.198905] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.199182] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.873787] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    2.805390] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.805471] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.805573] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
[    2.805640] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    2.805653] Init: Power Port (0)
[    2.806286] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    2.806314] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.806335] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.806352] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.83+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    2.806368] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
[    2.807877] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.810166] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.821827] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.821846] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   21.424210] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   21.456790] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-w.txt failed with error -2
[   21.748438] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   21.748698] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[   21.750275] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Oct 22 2019 01:59:28 version 7.45.98.94 (r723000 CY) FWID 01-3b33decd
```

So it seems that USB actually detects devices but somehow fails?? This is super strange...

Connecting/disconnecting devices to USB does not change lsusb output... I also tried to install new fresh Raspberry Pi OS, thinking that maybe some USB drivers got corrupted after "The Great Incident", but no, USB have same behavior in fresh system...

What can this be and is it possible for me to somehow fix it myself? Maybe by checking/changing some component on board?

Comment: so, you made some unspecified changes to USB connectors, and now the USB subsysyem is failing? ... reverse what you did

Comment: What you mean by "reversing"? I can't reverse time and not do what I did to see if this was the reason of USB fail. I'm only hoping that people would spot the possible reason from logs and description.